# Assign double-click handler function to ng-grid after initialisation

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I found [this way](http://developer.the-hideout.de/?p=113) to use a plugin for ng-grid, which handles double click events.

My Problem with this approach is, that i must set the actual function handling the double click event after the grid was rendered. So how to solve this?

Is there a way to reload gridOptions?